# Bootstrap 5 tab panes not working with flexbox properly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am using barebones Bootstrap 5 tabs(pills) setup straight from [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/) page:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

I then populate `tab-pane`s with `floating-div`s:

```
.floating-div {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.pane-1 {  
  background-color: green;  
}

.pane-2 {  
  background-color: orange;  
}

.pane-3 {  
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

Up to this point everything works as expected - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/comparebest/dLpeu230/7/) .

Then I am applying standard bootstrap's flexbox classes to `tab-pane`s to align tab content to my liking `d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between`.

That's where the whole thing went downhill - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/comparebest/dLpeu230/12/) .

The way the content in the first `tab-pane` lays out is what I am after, but for some reason content in all the other `tab-pane`s is shifted down. Not only that, but, on the close inspection it appears that each of the `tab-pane`s contain ALL the `floating-div`s that supposed to be spread out across 3 different divs, some of them are just invisible...

Now my question is: Is there something wrong with my CSS or with the way I use Bootstrap's flexbox classes, or is it a bug in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the "`.d-flex`" attribute comes with the "`display: flex! Important`" specifier.

But "`.tab-content> .tab-pane`" only uses "`display: none`" format. In this case, "`.d-flex`" will dominate and will remain as "`display: flex`" in all cases.

On the other hand, since "`opacity: 0`" is invisible, but it will take up space.

To solve this,

#### Method 1:

Create a new element inside "`.tab-pane`".

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>  
</div>
</div>
```

#### Method 2:

Writing a new class.
"`.d-maybe-flex`"

```css
.d-maybe-flex
{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade show active d-maybe-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>  
</div>
```

#### Example 1

```css
.floating-div {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.pane-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.pane-2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.pane-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Green</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Ornage</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Blue</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
      <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
      <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
      <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example 2

```css
.d-maybe-flex {
  display: flex
}

.floating-div {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.pane-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.pane-2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.pane-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Green</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Ornage</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Blue</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active d-maybe-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade d-maybe-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
    <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade d-maybe-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
    <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
    <div class="floating-div pane-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```